# Stormpath to Okta migration

Tags: authentication, okta, stormpath

We are currently using Stormpath for authentication. Our web application seems to be using a combination of Stormpath SDK calls and some REST calls.

I am aware that the Stormpath SDK will be shutting down August 17, 2017.

I'm trying to get my head around how we are going to migrate our code to Okta or even if we should. Should I just plan on rewriting the authentication portion of our application from the ground up? Stormpath says that [Okta has not rewritten the SDK but will have REST apis that we can use temporarily](https://stormpath.com/oktaplusstormpath). That sounds somewhat flaky.

Are there alternatives to Okta? My first priority is to find a service that is as stable as possible so that we don't have to migrate again anytime soon.

Comment: Which Stormpath SDKs are you using?

Comment: Hey @nettie - a lot of this depends on how your current application uses Stormpath. Some of our libraries will be ported over to Okta (Spring, Express, ASP.NET), and others won't. I know "it depends" is a frustrating answer, but we're definitely happy to help - too broad for a StackOverflow thread, but you can reach out to support@stormpath.com and we'd be happy to assist.

Comment: @MattRaible stormpath-sdk-impl, stormpath-shiro-core, stormpath-sdk-oauth, stormpath-sdk-httpclient, stormpath-sdk-api

Comment: @nettie definitely hit us up at support@stormpath.com we can talk more about which APIs you are using and your paths forward (with or without Okta).  There are a couple Shiro libraries that could help as well!

Comment: Auth0 seems to be one alternative. This article is worth reviewing. https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-migrate-your-existing-stormpath-users-to-auth0/